# TFS Build: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis, devops, tfs-2015

We have an issue, where developers were Renaming and Deleting files in our Visual Studio SSIS project. Received this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '..SSISPackage.dtsx'

2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Project.IDEProjectStorage.LoadStream(String streamName)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadStreamToEnd(IProjectStorage storage, String streamName)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadPackage(IProjectStorage storage, Package package, String streamName, IDTSEvents events)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
2019-02-07T02:29:05.5297338Z    at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
```

We went to Visual Studio and Cleaning Solution. --> Clean files and Rebuild Solution. We tried this several times but did not work, so I Closed and Restarted Visual Studio on my desktop and for several developers. The problems and errors went away.

Now we have same issue on TFS 2015 Server. I tried to Clean solution and also Delete the Workspace files in TFS task. It does not work. What is the equivalent of 'Restarting' this on TFS, or how do I clear the memory cache? Our last option is to restart the server, has to be better way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a template empty fake file to replace the missing file and complete your check-in. After the file is checked in, it should build correctly. Then delete the file not required.